# start script as soon as the page opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery script that changes an element to fixed when the page is scrolled.

The problem is that the script won't work until the page is fully loaded, and it can take some time

Is there a way to start the script as soon as the user enters the page, without having to wait until it finishes loading ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
var menuOffset = $('#ribbonmenu')[0].offsetTop;

$(document).bind('ready scroll', function() {
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (docScroll >= menuOffset) {
        $('#ribbonmenu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#ribbonmenu').removeClass('fixed');
    }

});
});//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: No, because probably at the time the script would start running, your `#ribbonmenu` html won't have been loaded/parsed yet, so the script will fail. Javascript cannot timetravel and see that the element WILL exist in the future. it'll just see it doesn't exist NOW and bail out.

Comment: if you need parts of the DOM to be there, you have to wait.

Comment: Either add the script before the `</body>` tag or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `$(window).load(`
you could try using `$( document ).ready(`.

It will load sooner, but as others have mentioned, there isn't a way to get it to load instantaneously and still work. This is because future elements will not have loaded yet.

Comment: He doesn't want to wait for the page to load.

Comment: He can't run scripts on elements before the page is loaded, and .ready() executes before .load()

Comment: I understand that, but do you expect that using ready instead of load will make his script run faster?

Comment: Not faster, but sooner.

Comment: Regardless, this answer goes against what he said he wanted. And that was to have it execute instantly. If his script is taking a noticeable amount of time to execute then it's probably not the function he's using, but rather a slow server. I doubt using `ready()` will make a visible difference.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't provide exactly what he wants, and may not really show much difference. It's better than nothing though, and depending on page will be greatly improved

Comment: @Nicolas With large images or a slower internet connection, the difference can easily be seen. The `ready` event occurs when the `document` has finished loading (markup has been parsed), while `load` also waits for any linked media. The script only needs the `document` to be ready.

Comment: I got a LOT of images on my page, so using document ready instead of window.load already makes it a bit faster, thanks ! Still room for improvement, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, put it outside:

`$(window).load(function() {`

That will answer your question about wanting your script to run instantly, however there are issues beyond just moving it outside the load function.

As Marc B said, your script which calls upon an HTML element will not run if it is outside your load function because for a very, very, small time period the HTML hasn't loaded and your script will not see your HTML.

This will cause an error thus making your script not work as intended. Therefore you should keep it inside the load function and instead look for alternative ways to speed up your server/script.

Comment: I have referred to Marc B's comment.

Comment: What if i put the script AFTER the html element ? The element should load first, then the script ?